# Loading CSS file after window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the print margins of a window.
I use the next code(in "PrintDiv") to open and print the window.
My problem  is the print margins is not working.

I suspect css is not been found to load when using the new window.
But, I and not sure, because after the print dialog open, I can´t to see the chrome console to be sure about it.

In others  html pages I just use the next to load the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/css/print.css" media="print" >
```

But, when opening a new window, it´s not working.

Image from chrome dev tool :
[image]

Here is the wrong margins print
[image]

--print.css file--

```
@page{
    margin: 10cm;  
}
```

--script--

```
function PrintDiv(){
 var w = window.open('');
 var html = '<div>test</div>'; 
 loadStyle(w,'/files/css/print.css');
 $(w.document.body).html(html);
 w.document.close;
 w.focus();
 w.print();
 w.close();
}

function loadStyle(w,href, callback){
    // avoid duplicates
    for(var i = 0; i < w.document.styleSheets.length; i++){
        if(w.document.styleSheets[i].href == href){
            return;
        }
    }
    var head  = w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = w.document.createElement('link');
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = href;
    link.media="print";
    if (callback) { link.onload = function() { callback() } }
    head.appendChild(link);
    console.log(w.document)
}
```

To JensV:
[image]

To Rachel:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you simply remove `w.print();` and `w.close()` to be able to use the Developer Tools in the popup?

Comment: I’m not sure a relative URL to the stylesheet will work here - your popup window probably doesn’t have a “base URL” that it could resolve this against. Try an absolute URL and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hi, I follow the suggestions from you. I put attached the image from developer tools. There is no error loading the script. But the margins is not working

Comment: @LuizAlves it may be a problem with reading mm? you could try ``@page {margin: 10cm }``

Comment: @Rachel Gallen I just did. I have the same problem

Comment: @LuisAlves Do you have `@media print`  brackets around it? I know it sounds obvious but sometimes it's the little things!

Comment: @Rachel Gallen I think is no needed because the CSS link already has media=print

Comment: @LuizAlves That may be the mistake. Put your print CSS between `@media and print { CSS here } `brackets.  and see how you go.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen  It was solved. It was the media bracket. Thank  you very much.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help

Comment: @Rachel Gallen Sorry too early. The problem continues. Here is my css media print{  
  @page{
    margin: 10cm;  
  }
}
If I change the margin, there is no  change on print dialog.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen Sorry. My mystake. I unmarked  it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the dimensions of a standard A4 page are 210mm x 297mm, so your margin of 100mm on all sides seems excessive - at max you would have 1cm of printing area in the middle, and that's if there was no extra padding. US Letter is smaller, so unless you are printing on a very large page, I would suggest you reduce the margins, even slightly, to maybe 7 or 8 cm at maximum.

Your print css inside your style css should have the following format:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    margin: 7cm;
  }
  header, footer, nav {
     display: none; /*e.g*/
  } 
}
```

To specify print margins for left and right of your page you can also use

```
@page :left{margin:2cm;}  and
@page :right{margin:8cm;}   /*sizes used are purely for example*/
```

I note that in your comment you omitted the '@' sign. Ensure you type `@media` (with the @), and that the media query brackets around the other css specs are closed.

You can include other/all css in the same css stylesheet, just ensure that screen media queries are surrounded by `@media screen{}` brackets .

You can remove the `"media=print"` from the css link in your html.

Hope this helps

(Another thing I noticed in your question is that you seem to be closing the document body before printing it? This may be hindering the print. Try closing it after.)

Comment: @LuisAvales I would comment out the console.log line of the function too, once I knew that w.document was loading. It does work better in my experience if all css is in one stylesheet

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is my code:function PrintDiv() {
   var w = window.open('');
   var html = "<p>I have tried your solution. The CSS is loaded into the new window</p>";
   loadStyle(w,'http://127.0.0.1:8888/files/css/print.css',function () {
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
    w.document.close;
    w.focus();
    w.print();
    w.close();
  });
}

\@media print {  
 \ @page{
    margin: 7cm;  
  }
}

Comment: The print dialog shows the content as in the image posted to @JensV. In the code above I put a \ before media print only to solve problem to post in that comment

Comment: I attached the print dialog image, using the code above

Comment: @LuizAlves what are you printing? Are you using an external plugin or anything, a pdf plugin or something like that, or do you just want to print html to paper? Did you put all your style in one document and remove the "media=print" from the stylesheet link?

Comment: I am testing to print something as "var html = "<div>I have tried your solution. The CSS is loaded into the new window</div>";". After I get it working I will change the content to other  html text.

Comment: The problem is with the css. If I get rid off the css loading, it prints ok. But I need to use the css to set margins.

Comment: "Did you put all your style in one document and remove the "media=print" from the stylesheet link? "  Yes , I did

Comment: @LuizAlves One suggestion - set your printer to preview before print (and print to file to save the paper!) The media query for print should be at the end of the css

Comment: I am already using print preview. The attached images posted above are from print preview. Do you see the image posted to you?

Comment: @LuizAlves the print preview looks correct then, for the margins you are assigning it. Like I said in my answer, an A4 page is only 210mm wide, and you are setting very wide margins. Usually margins would only be between 1cm (10mm /1cm or  2cm (20mm). You may be misunderstanding what size margins you want?

Comment: No, It is not. If I put "margin: 10mm;" or other value there is no effect. The image stays the same. Then, the  margins is not been used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192388/discussion-between-rachel-gallen-and-luiz-alves).

Comment: Solved. You was sure. It was a cache problem. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Is there a way to set page margins with jquery and get rid off the cache margins setings problem?

Comment: @LuisAvales well it wouldn't make a difference if it was jquery or not. You can set a cache control in your header though. The  guidelines to setting a cache expiry have changed a few times so look up how to do it. It's possible though.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the style has actually been loaded:

```
function PrintDiv(){
 var w = window.open('');
 var html = '<div>test</div>'; 
 loadStyle(w,'/files/css/print.css', function () {
   $(w.document.body).html(html);
   w.document.close;
   w.focus();
   w.print();
   w.close();
 });
}
```